# Cassandra C# results keep incrementing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cassandra

please note i'm a beginner with cassandra

I'm using a Cassandra database on a 3 node cluster. I'm connecting using the datastax c# driver. Nothing is running on the cluster as i'm using it for testing. (100% guaranteed)

i have a query would normally return over 1 million rows. however when i execute the code below i have 5000 rows returned.

then when i close the console application and run it again i get 10,000 rows returned.
i close the application again and run again i get 15,000 rows returned (in the count)

any idea what's happening. (how do i get as many rows as i want in batched and why does it keep incrementing by 5000 after closing the application in visual studio)

code is below.

```
 ISession session = null;

        try
        {
            var ips = new List<string>() { "111.111.111.111", "222.222.222.222", "333.333.333.333" };
            Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints(ips).Build();
            session = cluster.Connect("dbname");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


        var result = session.Execute("select * from dbname.tableName where id = 221");
        var count = result.Count();

        session.Cluster.Shutdown();
        session.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Are you aware of the [paging mechanism](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.6/#automatic-pagination-of-results)? I'm not sure if is the case here, but I think is worth investigating

Comment: The [default page size is 5000](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/201fb0049cd0ae7b21359b4330da0ad81d8a559a/src/Cassandra/QueryOptions.cs#L43). [Here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/) you can read some more about paging in the C# driver docs and on the documentation for the Java driver you have some more detailed explanations regarding [pagination](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/).